# Remove Nothing values from multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, multidimensional-array

How can I remove values having "Nothing" and reduce the array to the ones having values?

lets say I have a 2 dimensional array called `modvaluestmp(,)` I used the following **linq** statement to remove nothing. It worked but the resulting array (result) is a single dimensional array. Can someone help me return a 2D array preserving the indexes ?

```
Dim result() = (From str In modvaluestmp
              Where Not {Nothing}.Contains(str)).ToArray()
```

the existing array is something like this

```
modvaluestmp(0,0) = "sometext1"
modvaluestmp(0,1) = "sometext2"
modvaluestmp(0,2) = "sometext3"
modvaluestmp(0,3) = "sometext4"
modvaluestmp(0,4) = Nothing
modvaluestmp(0,5) = Nothing
modvaluestmp(1,0) = "sometext5"
modvaluestmp(1,1) = "sometext6"
modvaluestmp(1,2) = "sometext7"
modvaluestmp(1,3) = "sometext8"
modvaluestmp(1,4) = Nothing
modvaluestmp(1,5) = Nothing
```

I want the array to be as follows

```
modvaluestmp(0,0) = "sometext1"
modvaluestmp(0,1) = "sometext2"
modvaluestmp(0,2) = "sometext3"
modvaluestmp(0,3) = "sometext4"
modvaluestmp(1,0) = "sometext5"
modvaluestmp(1,1) = "sometext6"
modvaluestmp(1,2) = "sometext7"
modvaluestmp(1,3) = "sometext8"
```

Comment: How can you both preserve the indexes **and** eliminate some values? Please edit your question to give an example of an original array and what you want to end up with.

Comment: That method returns single dimensional arrays, try using a loop and if statements to search out the value of Nothing

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom can u give an example for that ?

Comment: @Blackwood sry i actually dont want to preserve the index, My bad. I just need to remove values in my array having Nothing.

Comment: What you probably want is a [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t(v=vs.90).aspx), not a multidimentional array. `String()()`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå no actually i need a multidimentional array.

Comment: @Blackwood  edited the question to include an example.

Comment: LINQ doesn't work well with 2D arrays.

Comment: No, actually you need a jagged array.

Comment: @HansPassant so its not possible to achieve what i want with the existing setup ?

Comment: It's possible, but only if you want to have the **same** number of indices in your last dimension.  If you require different lengths then the jagged array (or List of Lists) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jagged-array](/questions/tagged/jagged-array) instead square 2D Array. So your codes should like this:

```
 Dim modvaluestmp = New String(1)() {}

 modvaluestmp(0) = New String(5) {}
 modvaluestmp(1) = New String(5) {}

 modvaluestmp(0)(0) = "sometext1"
 modvaluestmp(0)(1) = "sometext2"
 modvaluestmp(0)(2) = "sometext3"
 modvaluestmp(0)(3) = "sometext4"
 modvaluestmp(0)(4) = Nothing
 modvaluestmp(0)(5) = Nothing
 modvaluestmp(1)(0) = "sometext5"
 modvaluestmp(1)(1) = "sometext6"
 modvaluestmp(1)(2) = "sometext7"
 modvaluestmp(1)(3) = "sometext8"
 modvaluestmp(1)(4) = Nothing
 modvaluestmp(1)(5) = Nothing

 Dim result = (From ary In modvaluestmp Select ary.Where(Function(str) Not str Is Nothing).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Help links:

[jagged arrays in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)

[jagged arrays in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. You only have **trailing** empty elements in your array
2. You want to truncate all the rows so they have the same number of
   elements (possibly losing data)
3. Each row has at least one element in it

Then you can determine which row is the smallest and use `ReDim Preserve`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim modvaluestmp(,) As String = {
        {"sometext1", "sometext2", "sometext3", "sometext4", Nothing, Nothing},
        {"sometext5", "sometext6", "sometext7", "sometext8", Nothing, Nothing},
        {"sometext9", "sometext10", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing}
    }

    Console.WriteLine(DisplayArray(modvaluestmp))

    Dim max As Integer = modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(1)
    For y As Integer = 0 To modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(0)
        For x As Integer = modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(1) To 0 Step -1
            If Not IsNothing(modvaluestmp(y, x)) AndAlso x < max Then
                max = x
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ReDim Preserve modvaluestmp(modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(0), max)
    Console.WriteLine(DisplayArray(modvaluestmp))
End Sub

Private Function DisplayArray(ByVal arr(,) As String) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For y As Integer = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
        For x As Integer = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(1)
            sb.Append(If(x = 0, "", ", ") & arr(y, x))
        Next
        sb.AppendLine("")
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Output:

```
sometext1, sometext2, sometext3, sometext4, , 
sometext5, sometext6, sometext7, sometext8, , 
sometext9, sometext10, , , , 

sometext1, sometext2
sometext5, sometext6
sometext9, sometext10
```

--------- Edit ----------

Here's an example of using a `List(Of List(Of String)`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim modvaluestmp(,) As String = {
        {"sometext1", "sometext2", "sometext3", "sometext4", Nothing, Nothing},
        {"sometext5", "sometext6", "sometext7", "sometext8", Nothing, Nothing},
        {"sometext9", "sometext10", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing},
        {"sometext11", "sometext12", "sometext13", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing}
    }

    Dim stamps As New List(Of List(Of String))
    For y As Integer = 0 To modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim newRow As New List(Of String)
        For x As Integer = 0 To modvaluestmp.GetUpperBound(1)
            If Not IsNothing(modvaluestmp(y, x)) Then
                newRow.Add(modvaluestmp(y, x))
            End If
        Next
        stamps.Add(newRow)
    Next

    For Each row As List(Of String) In stamps
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", row))
    Next

    ' Example of accessing an element directly:
    Console.WriteLine("stamps(0)(2) = " & stamps(0)(2))
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure...but if all the rows don't have the same number of elements, you'll either have to truncate elements or keep some rows with Nothing in them.  If you want a variable number of elements then go with the jagged approach.

Comment: ya unfortunately the elements wont be of the same size everytime. but thanks anyways for the code. would help me somewer down the line. :) and yes ill take the jagged array